# One of my data is not normally distributed, but is homogeneous, what test should I use?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, normality-assumption

when testing for normality and homogeinity in SPSS, it showed this:

[image]

I use shapiro-wilk result, and it shows that E25 is not normally distributed. but the homogeinity based on mean showed that it is homogen. what test should i use?

Comment: Why do you care about this? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is for my thesis research, I'm trying to find out whether the data differences were significant or not.